# How do we get something unique like pod id or container id in kubernetes deployment yamls

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm working on setting up a kubernetes pod for a service.There is a need to use persistent volumes for logs,certs etc which should be available at some sub-path at host like service/log.Now i want to make this folder unique by changing to something like service/log_podID or log_podName.How can i get a pod name or pod id within in k8s deployments yamls.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow, your question is very broad and it's very hard to answer specific. Consider to read the [How to ask](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and maybe add some example configuration so others could reproduce your issues.

Answer (score 2):

Using something like this implies some kind of state which is contrary to the stateless nature of a `Deployment`. You could use the `hostname` within the container to have a unique ID, but that can't be used in the YAML.

If you need reliable IDs of your PODs you should use a `StatefulSets` ([documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/)) which bring predictable pod names which you could then use within your yaml.